# Escape tower details of Mercury spacecraft

Tags: project-mercury, launch-escape-system

In the details about the escape tower for the Mercury capsule, I noticed that it had three nozzles, all connected to a single combustion chamber of the solid propellant.

How did the designers ensure that exhaust from the combustion chamber was distributed equally between these three nozzles?

If the distribution were not equal, one (or two) of the nozzles would develop more thrust, and thus were likely to provide an unequal and **uncontrolled** tilt while escaping.

If interested, you may refer to the details provided in the book "Project Mercury - A chronology" (NASA - SP 4009) on page 49. [image: page 49]

Comment: FYI, a liquid engine with a similar one chamber, multi-nozzle design https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45222/6944

Comment: The center of mass of the capsule/escape rocket is below the exhaust (like a bottle rocket) rather than above. Doesn't that make the assembly inherently directionally stable?

Comment: @Organic Marble: YES, it did have 18 small nozzles. All of them were collectively lifting one engine, which was physically attached to a much larger body of the lander. There were three such sets of engine. I therefore assume that individual offset thrust of each engine, would have been collectively mutually compensating. As a result, effective collective imbalance (from all the three engines) was almost zero. In case of Mercury, it was a different case of operation. Nevertheless, as an example of LF rocket with one combustion chamber and multiple nozzles, I accept the fact. Thanks.

Comment: @Woody: The center of mass being below the rockets, will only reduce the effect of unwanted tilting forces. The imbalance would still be there.

Comment: @Woody - that's the pendulum rocket fallacy, and is indeed a fallacy, alas. The key point to recognize it as a fallacy is that if the rocket tilts, the direction of thrust _also_ tilts the same amount and in the same direction. If the thrust happens to be slightly off-axis, _it will remain so_ - without stabilization the rocket will end up moving in a circle (or more likely, lithobraking.)

Comment: @TLW ... good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They "...ensure(d) that exhaust from the combustion chamber was distributed equally within these three nozzles." by test and redesign.

The first test on March 8, 1959 of a three-nozzle system went badly wrong due to asymmetric thrust just as you said might happen "an unequal and uncontrolled tilt while escaping"!

> Three Langley engineers, cha­grined by this threat to their work, conducted a full postmortem following the
> recovery of the capsule. They blamed the erratic behavior on a graphite liner
> that had blown out of one of the three exhaust nozzles.

A redesigned system was tested on April 12, 1959 with improved results

> Space Task Group conducted the second full-scale beach abort test on
> Wallops Island. A deliberate thrust misalignment of 1 inch was programed
> into the escape combination. Lift-off was effected cleanly, and a slow pitch
> started during the burning of the escape rocket motor. The tower separated
> as scheduled and the drogue and main parachutes deployed as planned. The
> test was fully successful.

Sources:

- [Project Mercury, a Chronology](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19630011968/downloads/19630011968.pdf?attachment=true)
- [This New Ocean, A History of Project Mercury](https://ia600208.us.archive.org/4/items/thisnewoceanhist00swen/thisnewoceanhist00swen.pdf)
- [Full-scale flight test from sea level of an abort-escape system for a Project Mercury capsule](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19670022198/downloads/19670022198.pdf?attachment=true) (describes the second test, but only mentions the first one)

Comment: As I said, I have raised the doubt after reading in the books mentioned by you. The text does not explicitly mention about three nozzles on one combustion chamber. The text runs as if its a historical story rather than a "Cause & Effect" analysis of a failure.